# A typedef can resolve to one of two types, but both seem impossible to me

Tags: c, relic

I see a type (fb_t) defined like so in the RELIC library (docs here https://code.google.com/p/relic-toolkit/downloads/list):

```
#if ALLOC == AUTO
typedef align dig_t fb_t[FB_DIGS + PADDING(FB_BYTES)/(FB_DIGIT / 8)];
#else
typedef dig_t *fb_t;
#endif
```

(`align` is defined as `/* empty */`, if it matters)

So it's a pointer, or it's an array. But if it's an array, then how would this function work? (from `relic-doc/html/df/d96/relic__fb__util_8c_source.html#l00080`)

```
void fb_copy(fb_t c, const fb_t a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < FB_DIGS; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i];
    }
}
```

And if it's a pointer, how would this code work (since they're uninitialized pointers)?

```
//create two variables 
fb_t source, target;
fb_copy(target,source); //and copy one to the other
```

Both are run from the same computer. The `sizeof(fb_t)` on this computer is 16.

Comment: I just remembered how function arguments work with array types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if it's an array, then how would this function work?

Very well, thanks. Why wouldn't it work?

> And if it's a pointer, how would this code work (since they're uninitialized pointers)?

If passed uninitialized pointers, it wouldn't work (it would cause undefined behavior instead).

**But:** I strongly suspect that, since the typedef depends on an `#ifdef` (which seems to control automatic vs. dynamic memory allocation), this case is covered in a safe way too (i. e. whichever part of the code used uninitialized `fb_t` objects would be excluded from the compilation when `fb_t` is defined as a pointer.)

Answer (score 2):

The function `fb_copy` above, works correctly irrespective of `fb_t` being an array or pointer. And that's because of the equivalence of arrays and pointers.

Consider this (read the comments):

```
    int a[10];
    int *ip;

    ip = a; 
    // this assignment is as if you have written ip = &a[0]
    // the first facet of equivalence
```

The second is, you can use the `[i]` syntax of accessing array elements, with pointers as well.

```
     int a = ip[3]
     //it is just as if you had written *(ip + 3)
```

By equivalent , we mean that though pointers and arrays are different, pointer arithmetic and array indexing are equivalent and tied.

So in this case that you've pointed out, if that function is passed **initialized pointers** , it does the equivalent of `*(c+i) = *(a+i)`